# Convergence of non-collapsing sequences of Riemannian manifolds with biliterally bounded sectional curvature

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**EDIT:** I heard that there is the following result:

Given a sequence $\{(M_i^n,g_i)\}$ of compact smooth $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds with uniformly bounded absolute value of sectional curvature, uniformly bounded above diameter, and uniformly bounded away from zero volume. Then there exists a subsequence which converges to a compact Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ **weakly** in the Sobolev space $L^{2,p}$ for any $p<\infty$.

(The relavant definitions can be found at these lecture notes by M. Anderson:https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0208079.pdf)

As far as I understand, in particular that means that there exist diffeomorphisms
$f_i\colon M\to M_i$  such that the Riemann curvature tensor of $f_i^*g_i$ converges to the one of $g$ weakly in $L^p$ for any $p<\infty$.

> I am wondering whether the conclusion on the weak convergence in $L^p$ is known to be really necessary, and it cannot be replaced by the strong convergence.
>   Are there reasonable extra assumptions on the sequence to guarantee the strong $L^p$ convergence of the Riemann curvature tensor?

Comment: I think the credit for this should really go to Stefan Peters and, independently, Greene and Wu. What Mike Anderson and Jeff Cheeger did was to show how to get the lower bound on the harmonic radius by a nice blowup argument. Anderson used, I believe, a similar argument in his paper on Einstein metrics.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Thank you, I deleted my imprecise reference.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Cheeger’s lemma. The heart of this theorem was the Cheeger finiteness theorem, which was his thesis. Gromov introduced Gromov-Hausdorff distance and showed how Cheeger’s theorem could be used to prove that a subsequence converges to a $C^1$ Riemannian manifold. Peters and Greene-Wu used harmonic coordinates to obtain stronger regularity results for the limit.

Comment: @DeaneYang : By Cheeger’s Lemma I meant the result that given an upper bound on absolute value of sectional curvature, upper bound on diameter, and lower bound on volume, one get a lower bound on injectivity radius.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I believe this is the argument for what you want: If the sequence converges strongly in $C^1$ (i.e., $W^{\infty,1}$) and weakly in $W^{2,p}$, then, by the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality, it converges strongly in $W^{2,q}$, for any $1 \le q < p$. Since this holds in the theorem for any $p > 1$, it follows that the sequence does in fact converge strongly in $W^{2,p}$, for any $p$.

Comment: @DeaneYang: could you post this as an answer with more detail on the relevant Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality and how it applies here?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, see below.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, you're right. Alas, what I wrote is completely wrong. Am deleting answer.